# Как найти номер строки по Id после сортировки?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица, которая сортируется с помощью `ORDER BY`:

```
+----+------+
| id | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | def  |
|  3 | ghi  |
|  4 | jkl  |
|  5 | mno  |
+----+------+
```

Как узнать порядковый номер строки с id 2 (столбец для выбора строки может быть другим) после сортировки таблицы по col1? Другими словами, в приведенном выше примере при сортировке таблицы по возрастанию строка `def` оказывается второй,  по убыванию - четвертой. Как получить этот порядковый номер?

Comment: Добавить в выходной набор ROW_NUMBER(). Ему чхать на сортировку, он всегда вернёт номер по порядку при текущей (или указанной в OVER, если имеется) сортировке. Само собой, придётся его зафиксировать - например, в CTE, если Вы намерены оставить только интересующую запись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [row_number](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select
    id,
    col1,
    row_number() over(order by col1 desc) as row_num
from #table
```

---

```
with NumberedRows as  
(
    select id, col1,
        row_number() over(order by col1 desc) as row_num
    from #table
)
select id, col1, row_num
from NumberedRows
where col1 = 'jkl'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но если я ограничиваю запрос с `WHERE`, то получаю `row_num = 1`. Нужно узнать порядковый номер конкретной строки, я не всех.

Comment: @XelaNimed - обновил ответ. Используем CTE, как в комментарии написал Akina.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, здесь СТЕ не нужен. Это если по номеру искать, т.е. по row_num.